# Will the cabin crew heat your own food up?

Tags: air-travel, airlines, aircraft, cabin-crew

Normally, you get a meal or two depending on the length of your flight. However, let's say that you also brought your own food with you (maybe a burger or ramen). Are you allowed to ask the crew to heat it up for you? If so, what's the best way to do that?

Comment: Allowed to ask? Certainly. Will they do it? It will most probably depend on each airline’s policy. Heating up baby bottles is something they usually do, I believe. Anything else is probably much less likely, for all sorts of reason including the risk of contamination.

Comment: Can the ramen be prepared by just adding some hot water? If so, ask for a cup of hot water when the drinks cart comes by.

Comment: also, define "heat up" - do you mean in a microwave? The hot meals are in a special cart that goes into a sort of oven thing and heats them all up at once. There are taps that dispense hot water. There may not be a microwave -- I think those baby bottles are heated by sitting in a bowl of hot water.

Comment: You may get more chances, if you ask for you heat on a very calm period (not during main service), e.g. when crew is just waiting and checking things are ok. Think about hygiene (their point of view): bought ramen is better then home mane recipients (maybe old with sign of time)

Comment: How on earth would they do this?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi That's actually a pretty good idea. However, as pointed out by Harper airplanes are unable to warm up foods such as burgers. So it better to take something that doesn't need to be warmed up or ramen :)

Comment: @SkiMask I'd be wary of even something like instant ramen. Cooking it properly needs water at or near 100 C, and I'd guess the crew are not going to provide that even if asked given that coffee and tea (which may be provided) are usually about 85 C (too low to properly cook instant noodles), and heating a baby bottle is even lower than that.

Comment: @jcaron How can you possibly gather that much reputation without knowing that you shouldn't answer questions in the comment section? Are you simply blatantly ignoring the policy and the explicit warning against it that is presented every time you write a comment?

Comment: interestingly this is a dupe!  but I can't find the original.

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000543133506.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.34f33018DSNQmU&algo_pvid=42c493d9-b8b1-4328-9050-3eabb9f4ea62&algo_expid=42c493d9-b8b1-4328-9050-3eabb9f4ea62-0&btsid=0be3769015957112435456512e3f6a&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_  Not sure if this will work

Comment: Korean airlines or other international airlines will make instaramen that you brought for you (put hot water and bring it back to you)

Comment: I would like to see how you manage to bring your own food through airport security in the first line...

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g I've never actually had a problem before. I bought Burger King from Munich Airport and they let it through. It probably depends on the place I guess.

Comment: @SkiMask Did you buy it landside (*before* passing through security), or airside (*after* passing through security)?  That's going to make a big difference.

Comment: @Chronocidal I bought it before passing the security. I just put the takeaway bag in the scanning tray and it was let through.

Comment: @Rg7xgW6acQ3g Where in the world is security concerned about food? Back when I was doing 100 flights/year (my weekly commute, in the EU), I routinely had multiple cooked meals in my carry-on. Never had the slightest issue with security. Just be careful not to include anything that would fall under "liquids" (a bit of gravy was never a problem). Can't imagine how a burger could be deemed a threat to flight safety.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

A cabin crewmember here.

The answer is: **No, it is NOT allowed!**

For various reasons, including:

1. **Security**: We do not know what are you heating, is it a heat-activated bomb? is it something that might make a lot of smoke? etc.
2. **Health**: We cannot contaminate the ovens, we know the source of the food that is provided by the airlines, we do not know the source of your food. Same ovens are used to heat the pilots' meals as well, we can't afford to have one of them having food poisoning in the middle of the flight?

The same goes for the refrigerators also.

Cabin crew do help passengers when it comes to babies' milk and so by providing hot water to heat up the bottle or a bag full of ice to cool things like medicines, but we shall never use the aircraft equipment to heat/cool any other food that is not provided by the airline.

There's a policy in the airline I work for that prohibits even the crewmembers from using the ovens/refrigerators to heat/cool their own food that they bring from outside the aircraft.

Some might say that they had a different experience and the crew helped them, yes it could happen when a crewmember decides to *violate* the rules to help a passenger based on his/her judgment, but that's not something to expect on every flight.

Factoids: there are various heating devices onboard airplanes, depending on the model and the airline, including Conventional ovens, steam ovens, microwave ovens, bun warmers, water heaters, steam wands, coffee makers, espresso machines, etc. Airlines and manufacturers have really taken these flying machines to the next level.

Comment: That kind of "we don't heat your food" policy is universal in every restaurant and cafeteria I've seen.  You can *get away with it* in convenience store style operations where you're expected to microwave your own popcorn or hot pockets... but any place a server puts the food in the oven, forget it.

Comment: Don't crewmembers typically eat the same meals the passengers get?

Comment: I had the same experience on a high speed train. Baby milk was GO, own meal was NO-GO. For the same health reason shown in the answer, as explained by the crew

Comment: @einpoklum yes, but sometimes they buy food from airports or bring their own from home, just like any passenger. Sometimes we just get bored from having the same choices for 3 or 4 months.

Comment: "is it a heat-activated bomb?" That's pretty ridiculous Bond-villain territory. If a passenger can smuggle a heat-activated bomb on board, they could also, more easily, have a push-button or timer-activated one. Should we ban in-flight Wi-Fi because someone could have a Wi-Fi-activated bomb?

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ I think it's not really the difference between baby milk and a meal -- it's the difference in providing a substance *for* the passenger (a bath of hot water to warm the milk, then discarding the water) versus accepting a substance *from* the passenger into a sanitary environment like an oven that's used for airline-provided food.

Comment: @nanoman that's not ridiculous, a bomb that is made from simple material is possible, an expert managed to buy the material from the duty free market, look it up in youtube.. It's never bad to be extra cautious.

Comment: @NeanDerThal I'm not saying the threat of a bomb is ridiculous; I'm saying the idea that a bad guy would base his design/plan on hoping to get a flight attendant to heat it, as opposed to simply having a trigger under the bad guy's direct control, is ridiculous.

Comment: @nanoman the whole airline safety is built on the concept of multi lines of defences. We cannot rely on airport security, we have to assume that someone managed to out-smart it, and so on. That's the whole idea, everyone assumes that they are the last line of defence and act accordingly.

Comment: @einpoklum There are extra regulations for cockpit crew members to prevent situations such as those in the movie [Airplane!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane!). This was mostly in response to an [incident in 1975](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Airlines_food_poisoning_incident). I used to have more sources on that; as far as I remember from one of them, there are separate crew meals, although crew members can also choose a passenger meal, as long as cockpit crew members eat different meals prepared by different cooks.

Comment: I think this (security) is an important point of debate. Prohibiting something just because we *might conceivably* foil a bad guy is a recipe for doing more harm than good. I think the security argument in this case is weak (better are food safety and overburdening flight attendants). It's a tradeoff of how much innocent/beneficial activity is impacted. Would you outlaw *maps* because they could help a terrorist find a target? The UK [essentially did this](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/21680/31845) (until a court clarified the law's interpretation). ...

Comment: ... Your "lines of defence" reasoning could also be used to ban Wi-Fi, as I noted. Suppose it were economical and safety-approved to install a temperature-limited personal oven, cleaned between flights, at each business-class seat for passengers to warm their own food. In this hypothetical, the bomb triggering concern is *not* a reason to ban the ovens IMO. There are so many simpler ways open. Bad guy can even generate heat with common, legal personal items (it might not be legal to *use* them this way in-flight, but bad guy won't care about that!).

Comment: Does that mean I can request truly hot water then?

Answer (score 21):

### They are unable to do so.

Most aircraft *don't even have* microwave ovens.

Not least, because of potential effects on avionics and sensors, not to mention power surge issues.

What they use for hot meal service is elaborate ovens made to heat many meals at once, provided they are packaged a particular way from the food supplier.  The oven doesn't lend itself to general use for single meals.

There is also hot water spigot service for tea, which is how they heat a baby bottle.  This might help with the ramen, but will get you nowhere with microwave fare such as burgers, pizza etc.

Comment: Ah. I actually never thought about how they actually warmed the food and always thought that they had some kind of an oven that warms it up. But this is good to know!

Comment: Do you have any example of an oven using engine bleed air? I found several companies selling aircraft ovens but they are electric.

Comment: *Aircraft do not have microwave ovens* This seems inaccurate. They seem to be rare, but some aircraft do have them. Also seconding request for a reference for ovens running off bleed air. I can't find any evidence of this.

Comment: @SkiMask, they do have ovens, but they are designed for heating the food packages that are served by the airline during the flight, not random items a passenger might bring on board. The flight attendants aren't going to take a chance that whatever you brought isn't going to make a mess or start a fire if put in the oven.

Comment: @MFlop I'll concede the "bleed air" point.  Keep in mind this sort of industrial arcana is really beyond the limits of the WWW.  The needed source material is too obscure and is not online. I have a feeling my "bleed air" belief dated to earlier aircraft; but *even still*, I can't believe they would use heavy, inefficient electric when hot bleed air is *abundant*.  (the inefficiency is converting from thermal to rotational; after that electric is perfectly efficient.)

Comment: Some aircrafts DO have microwave ovens. I can confirm that as a cabin crew!

Comment: @NeanDerThal Alright, alright.  This industry moves too fast lol.

Comment: @NeanDerThal Come to think of it, are you sure that's not a fast air-blast conventional oven?  Those are popping up all over at "light" food makers like Subway, coffee shops, Target has one in every cafeteria. They're as fast as microwaves and better controlled (no hotspots). They'd be a perfect match for the new discount-airline paradigm of paying for meals where you need to prepare one customer's at a time, and solve the microwave/avionics problem.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica It's a 100% microwave oven, seen it on a B777-200, it is not a standard oven in all models but it can be requested by the airline.

Comment: @NeanDerThal Presumably it is distant and/or shielded enough from the avionics to not be a problem.  If e.g., the kitchen is in the back of the plane, and the avionics are in the front, that should be more than enough to mitigate such problems.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I have no idea about the technicalities, but all the equipment onboard are provided by specific companies that manufacture things for airplanes, I am sure they know what they are doing and it will not affect the airplane's airworthiness.

Comment: One more thing, the oven can be used to heat up a single meal, this is usually done in business/first class if the meal service is provided on-demand, happens in long routes.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I have no idea why my comment merits such an unpleasant response. When someone questions my answers, I take it as a good faith effort to improve them. Please accept my comment as such a good faith effort, and withdraw your insult.

Comment: @MJeffryes I certainly didn't aim to insult *you* and I thought I made that clear. I'll cheerfully remove it.  I'm sure you've had helpful comments given to you by others, but it's a fallacy to presume yours are too. Look closely at the comments of others, and see *how* they are helpful.  Note how Naan establishes credential, did you?  Note how Darrell frames lay opinion as exactly that, did you?  Yes, our opinions differ; so what? Notably you asked for support but gave none.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Please don't insult my intelligence by pretending you did not insult me. It's a childish game of semantics to claim that you didn't call me a "sophomore pedant", and I'm not going to take lectures on helpfulness from someone who plays them.

Answer (score 17):

Cold food, such as a salad or cold sandwich, is likely to be easiest to bring on a plane. Reheating something, e.g. a burger, is very unlikely.

However, there is one way you can got hot food without asking the attendant for anything special. Pick instant soup, oatmeal, or indeed ramen, that can be prepared by adding hot, not necessarily boiling, water and waiting a specified time. During hot drinks service, when they are serving coffee etc, ask for one or two cups of hot water and use that to reconstitute your food. They serve tea as a cup of hot water and a tea bag, so the cart will have it.

Comment: I'm not sure tea served as hot water and tea bag is universal, is it?

Comment: @jcaron On flights I have been on even if they have pots of regular hot tea they also offer herbal teas in tea bags.

Comment: That makes sense. It'd be a lot easier to just bring ramen and ask them for warm water.

Comment: @jcaron: I’m sure it’s not absolutely universal, but in my experience (mostly from the US and Europe, but also reasonably widely across Asia and Australia) it’s extremely common and widespread.

Comment: A burger is basically a sandwich, so what makes it different enough to not be heated up?

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim A burger is a sandwich that needs to be heated to be appetizing. I have modified my answer to make it clear I meant cold sandwiches.

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim A burger doesn't necessarily have to be *eaten* hot, but it has to be *cooked* before eating, and unless it is frozen for storage after cooking it is then a breeding ground for bacteria.

Comment: @alephzero I suppose I was picturing a cooked burger that was just being warmed back up

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim That is also what I pictured, and the problem is that it needs to be warmed up. There are many sandwiches that are fine eaten cold.

Comment: Oh I see, since the question was "Can I heat up food?," I read your first sentence as "likely to be easiest [to get warmed up]." I see now you meant it as easiest to bring on a plane.

Comment: it's not "unlikely", it's totally impossible - as airliners do not have microwaves.

Answer (score 16):

**British Airways** will heat up milk for babies for you. You can certainly ask, but considering airlines are even reluctant to heat up the food they're serving to you, it would be a hard sell to ask them to heat up your personal food. Bring a salad or just wait until you land.

Comment: Thanks for your first answer on travel.stackexchange. Could you quickly explain why the cabin crew is reluctant to heat up the food they're serving you? In my experience i always burn myself on the food in the airplane.

Comment: I think it's more to do with the fact that they cannot, since they don't actually have an oven to warm up the food, as opposed to they are reluctant to.

Comment: Hot meals on flights are heated in special ovens designed to heat a lot of standard form-factor meals at once.

Comment: Any airliner will heat baby's milk: they just **use hot water**.  Airlines do not have any sort of over, whatsoever.  no microwaves, no conventional ovens.

Comment: @Fattie "Airlines do not have any sort of over" -- assuming you mean "oven", this is incorrect. Planes where hot meals are served have [convection ovens](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13337/40056).

Comment: right, there are specialized oven-like devices that heat whole massive racks of specially prepped airline meals.  but there are no "ordinary ovens" available for heating things, and no microwave ovens

Comment: airlines tend to heat their meals quite well, in my experience what you get it often piping hot if it's intended to be heated at all. This is not in the least to make sure any bacteria will have been killed...

Answer (score 2):

A few planes didn't have warming stoves or on the off chance that they did, they were stuck loaded with the dinner embeds that should have been warmed for the feast to be served inflight. Which implies there was no capacity to do as such. Likewise, if the flight is just so long, full with drink administration to do, at that point supper, at that point bar administration, at that point tidy up… .there basically isn't time as the entire thing is completely organized and planned to fit impeccably inside time boundaries.

Comment: On long flights there is plenty time between scheduled services, and as is shown in some other answers, on some flights cabin crew can and does heat up food. In most they don't but not for lack of time.